# Jquery ui sortables don't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm using jquery ui to make a sortable list but it doesn't work and I just can't understand why. The ul element receives the class 'ui-sortable' but nothing happens.

I made an example as the original js has many more unrelated objects.

The example is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Kx5A9/2/). To make it 'work' just click the button with 'editar' in it.

Comment: What jQuery UI version are you using on your real page?

Comment: I tested with both 1.8.23 and 1.8.22 and they seem to work - [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/Kx5A9/4/).

Comment: Have you changed anything in code, bro? It does work but it continues not to work on the real page...
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yeah I took a quick read in the code, didn't find anything strange. Check your console for errors in the page, there's probably something else giving a conflict or error.

Comment: The most strange part is that there are no errors in the console. I'll check the whole code to see if I can find anything. Thanks for the help once more!

Comment: I see errors in the console `Uncaught TypeError: Object function ( selector, context ) {
  // The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'
  return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context, rootjQuery );
 } has no method 'curCSS'`

Comment: I've seen it too but it doesn't appear at the real page.

Comment: In this case, please pass the "real page" so I will be able to find the problem there.

Comment: The real page is in http://template.meusite0800.com.br/main/ but as part of a most complex system, in order to get to the point where it happens, you have to follow this:
After accessing the page, you have to click the "Learn More" button and you'll be prompted with a modal where you have to click the button named "Novo" and finally, in the top menu click the "Páginas" link and you'll get there.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: got the new page, working on solution. at the meantime maybe you can find something useful at https://sites.google.com/site/guymograbi/developers-tools-for-web-development

Comment: it took me some time to reproduce the problem. you really need to modify the switch case 'php' thing.. took me a while. I am using 'html' suffix on the file. :) I will try to find a solution tomorrow

Comment: please edit your question to point to my reproduction. People can download my src from [my site](http://www.mograbi.info/stackoverflow/question_12328309/index.html) and also download the source from [the same place](http://www.mograbi.info/stackoverflow/question_12328309/src.zip). You can ignore the missing JPGs as this is definitely not the cause.

Comment: Guy, thanks a ton for all you effort to help.
I've tried your links in FF and Google Chrome but neither work... =(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After wasting a whole weekend with this issue, I ended up understanding what happened.
As [this comment](http://api.jquery.com/clone/#comment-42445276) points out: when adding elements in the dom using, .html(), it loses its events and data and that's why I wasn't able to clone a previously sortable ul.

I solved my issue assuring that the list was already at the dom before applying the sortable method to it.

Fabrício and Guy, thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: FWIW, I was at version 1.8.16, and just updating to 1.10 without changing anything else made this error go away.

Answer (score 0):

If you switch the fiddle to use JQuery 1.7.2 and JQuery ui 1.8.18 it works fine. probably compatibility issues. You can [see it in my version of your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kx5A9/12/)

The error I saw was

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function ( selector, context ) {
        // The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'
        return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context, rootjQuery );
    } has no method 'curCSS' jquery-ui.js:84
(anonymous function) jquery-ui.js:84
(anonymous function) jquery-git.js:5473
jQuery.extend.grep jquery-git.js:709
winnow jquery-git.js:5472
jQuery.fn.extend.filter jquery-git.js:5271
$.fn.extend.scrollParent jquery-ui.js:83
$.widget._mouseStart jquery-ui.js:3026
$.widget._mouseMove jquery-ui.js:677
$.widget._mouseDown._mouseMoveDelegate jquery-ui.js:650
jQuery.event.dispatch jquery-git.js:3060
jQuery.event.add.elemData.handle.eventHandle
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't change them in the real thing.
I just commented the other answer with the path for it.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue. In my case it was just a matter of finding and removing a duplicate jQuery include `<script>` tag.